# How to multiply NumericArrays element-wise?

Tags: list-manipulation, numeric-array

Normally, `Times` threads element-wise over lists, so we can use it to express element-wise multiplication of arrays:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}} {{a, b}, {c, d}}
(* {{a^2, b^2}, {c^2, d^2}} *)
```

But this does not hold for `NumericArray`s. Instead,

```
NumericArray[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4}]] NumericArray[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4}]]
```

stays as it is. I would have expected the output to be a single array, such as the result of

```
NumericArray[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4}] RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 4}]]
(* NumericArray[...] *)
```

How can I get this behaviour *without* using `Normal`? I obtain the arrays (dimensions typically `{10^6, 1}`) from a Python session, so they are already numeric, and I need the code to be fast.

Comment: It does! Thank you @JasonB.!